# MMUMapper Error Unexplained

Tags: android, eclipse

Got this error when just start developing app in my android device.
I didn't do nothing yet, just start a blank activity, run it over device and got this in the debug:

`09-15 23:13:08.487: E/MMUMapper(9757): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)`

Very annoying. Can anyone help me on how to get rid of this error? Please.
Thanks.